# Wordpress loading progess - wp-blog-header.php

Tags: php, plugin-development

I have a doubt about wordpress loading process. In maintenance mode will the `wp-blog-header.php` file used to display the admin dashboard?

Comment: I would have thought this would be relatively trivial to test for.

Comment: I've done some tests and for sure the file is loaded when the site is displayed. I don't know if this will happen also when the wp-admin dashboard is opened